# Model view matrix for a quad

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, graphics, 3d

For my graphics project I'm trying to implement a minimap. Unlike my usual objects I thought I could just specify the vertex coordinates in OpenGL's default camera coordinate system.
So I have my vertices at `(-1,1,0)`, `(1,1,0)`, `(-1,-1,0)` and `(1,-1,0)`. I don't use a projection matrix for the calculation of `gl_Position`. If I don't use a model view matrix, the quad with those 4 vertices fills the whole screen (as expected). Now I want to scale this quad to `100x100` pixels and put it in the upper right corner of the viewport, with a distance of `40` to the border of the viewport.

I tried to setup the model view matrix like this:

```
// Move to upper right corner - targetDistance
translate(vec3((viewportWidth - targetDistance) / viewportWidth, (viewportHeight - targetDistance) / viewportHeight), 0.0)
// Move upper right corner to origin
* translate(vec3(-0.5*targetWidth / viewportWidth,-0.5*targetHeight / viewportWidth, 0.0)
// Scale to desired size
* scale(vec3(targetWidth / viewportWidth, targetHeight / viewportHeight, 0.0)
```

The corresponding CPP code looks like this (uses glm).

```
glm::uvec2 viewportSize = this->camera->getViewportSize();
const float targetWidth = 100;
const float targetHeight = 100;
const float targetDistance = 40;

glm::mat4 modelViewMatrix =
  glm::translate(
      glm::vec3((viewportSize.x - targetDistance) / viewportSize.x,
                (viewportSize.y - targetDistance) / viewportSize.y, 0.0)) *
  glm::translate(glm::vec3(-0.5f * targetWidth / viewportSize.x,
                           -0.5f * targetHeight / viewportSize.y, 0.0f)) *
  glm::scale(glm::vec3(targetWidth / viewportSize.x,
                       targetHeight / viewportSize.y, 0.0f));
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The minimap gets scaled correctly and put in the upper right corner but there is no distance to the border (or even a negative one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fiddling with the vertex coordinate transformation I suggest something far more simpler? Just move the viewport itself into the desired corner and size of the window:

```
glViewport(
    lower_left_corner_in_the_window_in_pixels,
    lower_right_corner_in_the_window_in_pixels,
    width_in_pixels,
    height_in_pixels )
```

if your initial though on this "how should I do this? I set viewport in the resize (reshape) function" then you're doing it wrong. All calls to `glViewport` belong into the drawing process, i.e. should be placed in the drawing code, right before the OpenGL calls that depend on the viewport being set are done.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did. However, I fetch the current viewport before doing this and restore it after rendering, otherwise I would have to pass the window coordinates everywhere.

Comment: @SomeBody: What's wrong with passing the window coordinates around? Saving and restoring the viewport introduces yet another side effect / side channel. In general you want to minimize the amount of side effects and channels in a program; OpenGL by itself already has a crap-ton of side effects / channels, so if better not introduce yet another one. And if the program permits it, then plugging side channels by overrideing side effects by explicitly passed and set parameters is a good thing.